# Cuda ORB Descriptors Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to make a feature matching algorithm with OpenCV on CUDA.
I am using the ORB features.
The main problem I have is that I am able to well compute the ORB keypoints but the descriptors are always empty. I tried all the ways but without success. I tried with the last version of opencv (3.4.0) and the 3.2.0 version.
This is the simplified version of my code:

```
cv::Ptr<cv::cuda::ORB> orb_gpu = cv::cuda::ORB::create(5000);
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
cv::cuda::GpuMat descriptors;
cv::cuda::GpuMat img_gpu(curr_frame);
orb_gpu->detect(img_gpu, keypoints); 
orb_gpu->compute(img_gpu, keypoints, descriptors);
cv::Mat desc_cpu;
descriptors.upload(desc_cpu);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the direction of memory copy. You are calling `upload` instead of `download` function to copy descriptors from device to host. The following line is the culprit:

```
descriptors.upload(desc_cpu);
```

Replace it with:

```
descriptors.download(desc_cpu);
```

`upload` copies from host to device whereas `download` copies from device to host.

I have tested and verified the example with OpenCV 3.4 compiled with CUDA 8 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @Andrea... You may consider accepting the answer if it fixed your problem so that the question can be marked as solved :)